# grails rendering plugin fails with renderPdf

Tags: grails, pdf-generation

I'm having a problem with the grails rendering plugin. The controller prepares data and calls renderPdf

```
def reportergebnis = Reparaturauftrag.all.findAll{
    params.datumvon <= it.auftragsdatum && it.auftragsdatum <= params.datumbis && params.auftragsstatus.contains(it.auftragsstatus.id.toString())
}
renderPdf(template: 'report', model: [reportergebnis: reportergebnis], filename: 'report.pdf')
```

it doesn't want me though and throws out an NPE on the renderPdf call:

```
Caused by NullPointerException: null
->> 1337 | getPublicDeclaredMethods in java.beans.Introspector
```

The full stacktrace is on this [Pastebin Paste](https://pastebin.com/StxQvncT)

Any ideas about what this could be? 
I'm using grails 3 & gradle and pulled the plugin via `build.gradle` and `compile 'org.grails.plugins:rendering:2.0.3'`

Answer (score 0):

In the full stacktrace:

```
|    141 | $tt__reportexecute in ReparaturauftragController.groovy
|     96 | doInTransaction  in grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2
|    133 | execute . . . .  in org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate
|     93 | execute          in grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate
|    210 | invoke . . . . . in org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker
|    187 | invoke           in org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass
|     90 | handle . . . . . in org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter
|    963 | doDispatch       in org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
|    897 | doService . . .  in     ''
|    970 | processRequest   in org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet
|    861 | doGet . . . . .  in     ''
|    846 | service          in     ''
|     55 | doFilterInternal in org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter
|    317 | doFilter         in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    127 | invoke . . . . . in org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor
|     91 | doFilter         in     ''
|    331 | doFilter . . . . in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    115 | doFilter         in org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter
|     64 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter
|    331 | doFilter         in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     53 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|    331 | doFilter         in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    158 | doFilter . . . . in org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter
|    331 | doFilter         in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    169 | doFilter . . . . in org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
|    331 | doFilter         in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    200 | doFilter . . . . in org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter
|    331 | doFilter         in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     62 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|    331 | doFilter         in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    105 | doFilter . . . . in org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
|    331 | doFilter         in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     58 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter
|    331 | doFilter         in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    214 | doFilterInternal in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy
|    177 | doFilter         in     ''
```

there are several entries pointing to `org.springframework.security.web`.

Have you checked if the plugin is working as expected without authorization? If so, the problem is with security configuration.

Comment: I've set `grails.plugin.springsecurity.active: false` and it still fails https://pastebin.com/aaJk08r1

Comment: what's exactly in the line 139 of `ReparaturauftragController.groovy`?